# The derivative of $z=x^2+xy+ y^2$

Tags: derivatives

I have got confused about this problem, what I have thought was differentiating this with respect to $x$ gives -

$\frac{dz}{dx} = 2x + x \frac{dy}{dx} + y + 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$

But, I came across an online video which did it in this way-

$\frac{dz}{dx} = 2x + y$

How is this possible? What am I missing?

This is a three dimensional equation, so $y$ is not a constant, so this person cant treat $y$ as a constant I believe.

Comment: You're conflating "implicit derivatives" (your understanding) and "partial derivatives" (the video you saw).

Comment: Oh ok , so partial derivation is a special case of implicit derivate it seems.

Comment: for partial derivatives should one be using $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ rather than $\frac {dz}{dx}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=2x+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
but if $y$ doesn't depend on $x$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and then
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=2x+y$$

Comment: Oh ok , so partial derivation is a special case of implicit derivate it seems. Thank you , i was actually really disturbed watching the vedio. Will check this special case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply whether $x$ and $y$ are independent variables. If they are then, the approach in the video is legitimate, although one would normally write it as the partial derivative of $z$ wrt $x$. If $y$ depends on $x$, then your way is correct.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks